# Choosing the Correct Sampling Techniques

Tags: self-study, sampling

So I'm working on an assignment regarding sampling techniques that we covered in class. They are: simple random sampling, systematic sampling, stratified sampling, cluster sampling, multistage sampling, voluntary sampling, and convenience sampling. I'm stuck on two questions and I hope someone can help me.

Question 1: So this question asks us to list which sampling technique belongs to which sentence. Hopefully someone can tell me if I've picked the right one for the following sentences

1.You want to find out if your town is in favour of starting a composting pickup service. You ask everyone on your street. -I picked convenience sampling

2.A university is polling it's students. It selects 200 students at random in the same proportions as the enrollment in each department. -I picked stratified sampling

Question 2:
Suppose that you have to review a 300 page novel, but you have time to read only 15 pages. You decide to use systematic sampling to select these 15 pages. Describe the steps you need to carry out, show the calculation required, show the random number that you used and list the page numbers of the 15 pages that you will read. **Note: Everyone will be reading a different set of 15 pages.**

So the question I have for this one is what does the bolded part mean? Is it relevant to the question or can I just ignore it? And if it is relevant, where in my question does it fit.

Comment: Question 2 seems poorly worded. 300/15 = 20. So maybe there will be 20 readers each reading 15 pages and you are one of them. But if it's systematic sampling, I'm not sure how the 'random number' is relevant. Please check that you have transcribed the question correctly. // Answ to #1 OK.

Comment: @ BruceET Thank you for replying. Yay. I'm glad those two are correct. You're right, I messed up one of the words. It's supposed to be the random number you used, not need. I have fixed it in my post.